# Disadvantage of SMTP setup in AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to configure SMTP setup in AWS instance to get disk usage of AWS instance.
Is there any disadvantage or any point that we should keep in our mind before setup the SMTP in AWS server.
I am using mailutils for setup the SMTP by following given [link](http://rianjs.net/2013/08/send-email-from-linux-server-using-gmail-and-ubuntu-two-factor-authentication).

I am using EC2 instance.
Is there any way to setup email functionality in AWS ec2 instance.

Answer (score 2):

I would not set up SMTP for this purpose

Firstly, AWS generally block SMTP mail sending.  See this discussion on server fault

https://serverfault.com/questions/165854/my-ec2-instances-email-is-being-spam-blocked-by-gmail

Secondly, AWS has it's own built in monitoring and metrics system called "Cloudwatch"  Unfortunately it does not directly support disk space monitoring straight out of the box but AWS do tell you how to do it http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/mon-scripts.html

Comment: Removing the port 25 throttle can be accomplished by submitting a free request to AWS Support.  [The process](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/) also gives you custom reverse DNS for the Elastic IPs you select.  With correct SPF configuration, sending to Gmail (as mentioned in the linked question) doesn't seem to be a problem... but, the Cloudwatch solution is a good one, as is Simple Email Service (SES) -- which can be used by your SMTP server (if you still want one) as a smarthost, handling outbound delivery.

Comment: Thanks for post the answer. I have already setup SMTP in one AWS instance and It is sending mail of disk space information. But I am trying to setup in another machine and It doesn't work.